# Limiting CTE search based on FK for a Directed Acyclic Graph in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph, common-table-expression, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm still pretty new to raw SQL, having previously done everything in an ORM, and this probably just needs one extra line of SQL.

In my Postgresql DB I have the following tables: *nodes_table* and *edges_table* are pretty standard tables for defining a graph (specifically a DAG) within a Postgresql database.

I also have an *edges_group_table* which allows me to logically group together a bunch of edges. If the graph is a network of pipes, for instance, the edges_group_table might be used to specify which edges are in which building.

I have a working Common Table Expression (CTE) (shown below) to search for the ancestor nodes of a given node.

Because the graph may be huge, I want to be able to reduce the portion of the graph that the CTE has to search over. In addition to specifying the starting node, I want to be able to specify a group_id in order to limit the CTE search to those edges in the specified group.

Tables:

```
nodes_table
    id
    name

edges_table
    id
    name
    child_id -- a nodes_table id
    parent_id -- a nodes_table id
    group_id -- a edges_group_table id

edges_group_table
    id
    name
```

**How do I modify this CTE to limit the ancestor search of the graph to those edges within a provided group from edges_group_table?**

```
WITH RECURSIVE graph(id, depth) AS (
    SELECT first.parent_id, 1
        FROM edges_table AS first
        LEFT OUTER JOIN edges_table AS second
        ON first.parent_id = second.child_id
    WHERE first.child_id = 10 -- the node id we start from
UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT parent_id, graph.depth + 1
        FROM graph
        INNER JOIN edges_table
        ON edges_table.child_id = graph.id
)
SELECT id FROM graph
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY MAX(depth) DESC, id ASC
```

I appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it should be a straightforward as adding a WHERE clause to the recursive part of the CTE and to the first select clause, assuming you want to limit both searches:

```
WITH RECURSIVE graph(id, depth) AS (
    SELECT first.parent_id, 1
        FROM edges_table AS first
        LEFT OUTER JOIN edges_table AS second
        ON first.parent_id = second.child_id
            AND second.group_id = 15 --limit result for second node
    WHERE first.child_id = 10 -- the node id we start from
UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT parent_id, graph.depth + 1
        FROM graph
        INNER JOIN edges_table
        ON edges_table.child_id = graph.id
        WHERE edges_table.group_id = 15 --and all subsequent nodes
)
SELECT id FROM graph
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY MAX(depth) DESC, id ASC
```

Note that in the first expression we use the filter in the LEFT JOIN part rather than the WHERE clause so that it will return a row even if the first edge doesn't connect to a second edge within the designed edge group.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for. Thanks, George!